# compile lastest bnx2 driver on debian squeeze

Tags: debian, drivers, debian-squeeze, nic, broadcom

I want to upgrade the bnx2 network card driver in a Dell Power Edge R410. I downloaded the latest driver version from the broadcom website. If I want to compile the driver it fails with the following errors:

```
make
make -C bnx2/src  KVER=2.6.32-5-amd64 PREFIX=
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2-2.0.23b/src'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2-2.0.23b/src modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 2 modules
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2-2.0.23b/src'
make -C bnx2x/src KVER=2.6.32-5-amd64 PREFIX=
make[1]: Entering directory `/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src'
make -C /lib/modules/2.6.32-5-amd64/build M=`pwd` modules
make[2]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
  CC [M]  /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.o
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x.h:68,
                 from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:80:
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1009:1: error: "PCI_VPD_LRDT_ID_STRING" redefined
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:34:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1327:1: error: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x.h:68,
                 from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:80:
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1011:1: error: "PCI_VPD_LRDT_RO_DATA" redefined
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:34:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1328:1: error: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x.h:68,
                 from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:80:
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1013:1: error: "PCI_VPD_LRDT_RW_DATA" redefined
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:34:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1329:1: error: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x.h:68,
                 from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:80:
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1019:1: error: "PCI_VPD_SRDT_END" redefined
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:34:
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1334:1: error: this is the location of the previous definition
In file included from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x.h:68,
                 from /tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.c:80:
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1032: error: conflicting types for ‘pci_vpd_lrdt_size’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1355: error: previous definition of ‘pci_vpd_lrdt_size’ was here
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1037: error: conflicting types for ‘pci_vpd_srdt_size’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1366: error: previous definition of ‘pci_vpd_srdt_size’ was here
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1042: error: conflicting types for ‘pci_vpd_find_tag’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1391: error: previous declaration of ‘pci_vpd_find_tag’ was here
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1077: error: conflicting types for ‘pci_vpd_info_field_size’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1377: error: previous definition of ‘pci_vpd_info_field_size’ was here
/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_compat.h:1082: error: conflicting types for ‘pci_vpd_find_info_keyword’
/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-common/include/linux/pci.h:1403: error: previous declaration of ‘pci_vpd_find_info_keyword’ was here
make[5]: *** [/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src/bnx2x_main.o] Fehler 1
make[4]: *** [_module_/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src] Fehler 2
make[3]: *** [sub-make] Fehler 2
make[2]: *** [all] Fehler 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.32-5-amd64'
make[1]: *** [bnx2x.o] Fehler 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/netxtreme2-6.2.23/bnx2x-1.62.15/src'
make: *** [l2build] Fehler 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - try:

```
# cd bnx2/src
```

first and then do

```
# make && make install
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this problem is a minor change to bnx2x_compat.h.

around line 1178, add an "#ifndef:"

```
}
#endif

#ifndef PCI_VPD_LRDT
#if ((!defined RHEL_RELEASE_CODE) && (LINUX_VERSION_CODE ...etc...
```

And then close out the ifdef around line 1283:

```
}
#endif
#endif // !PCI_VPD_LRDT
#ifndef PCI_MSIX_FLAGS_QSIZE
#define PCI_MSIX_FLAGS_QSIZE 0x7FF
#endif
```

These two changes will allow the latest driver to build properly. I did it today with 1.72.18. A couple more minor changes are needed for a successful build on the v2.6 preemptive realtime kernel, changing __netif_tx_lock() to omit the smp_processor_id() second argument, but that's not required on the non-realtime kernel or realtime 3.0 and up.